# NavigationPush not working in flutter as it should do

Tags: flutter, dart

Navigation Push is working for the first Row() but after the Divider() its not working on the second Row(). WITHOUT ANY ERRORS. I DID WRAP MY MAIN PAGE IN Material App. I did cut some of the unnecessary code cuz it was too long. Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks in advance. and by the this feature in StackOverflow sucks that i have to write the detail of my problem as long as my code it self

````
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/b1.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: 20,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Buy. Sell. Exchange.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "eng",
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(2),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Search",
                        icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Cats
          Positioned(
            top: 130,
            left: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 315,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////                Houses
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (() {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const HouseRent()));
                          }),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 145,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 - 20,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                border: Border(
                                    right: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey, width: 0.2))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: const [
                                  Image(
                                    image: AssetImage("assets/house.png"),
                                    height: 50,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  Text(
                                    "Houses",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontFamily: "eng",
                                      //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "خانه",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      fontFamily: "dari2",
                                      //  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),                      
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      thickness: 0.2,
                      indent: 10,
                      endIndent: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////Mobiles
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (() {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const Electronics()));
                          }),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 144,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 - 20,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                border: Border(
                                    right: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey, width: 0.2))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: const [
                                  Image(
                                    image: AssetImage("assets/mobile.png"),
                                    height: 70,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 1),
                                  Text(
                                    "Mobiles",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontFamily: "eng",
                                      //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "موبایل",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      fontFamily: "dari2",
                                      //  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),), ],), ), ), ),),), ],),],),), ),)],),);}}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by extending the parent Container of Stack to cover all its children.